# Making android support all screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

I feel like I'm the only one lost here. Everyone seems to be fine with using DP to make apps work across multiple screen sizes. For me, whenever I load up another screen, the alignment will never be the scale properly.

However, if I use android:weight everything will scale fine across all devices. The problem I have with android weight for everything is that it doesn't always want to resize images well into layouts, not to mention the warnings I'll get for using nested weights.

One solution I see is creating a new screen size for each possible screen sizes out there. Is this what everyone else does? At first I thought we'd have to only create the x-large, small, etc layouts only to find that even these don't cope for various screen sizes (even the nexus 7 doesn't fall well into any of these categories).

Sample code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/yg" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
                style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:progress="50" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                style="@style/NormalFont"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar2"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/progressBar2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
                android:text="@string/exercise_percent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="100dip"
                android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:background="@drawable/start"
                android:onClick="meditateTask" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

For example, here the imagebutton I have will be out of place on every new screen size.

Comment: Can you provide example layout(s) and describe the problems you have with each one?

Comment: Added a sample layout that doesn't seem to want to align properly.

Comment: android:layout_weight is used to scale ONE dimension at a time **proportionally** (let's say in %, to esemplificate). Nested weights are **bad for performance**. Other than this, you can use **9 Patches**, **dp** (device independent pixels), and the good old **drawable and values** folders with ad hoc graphics and dimensions. **TABLETS** fall into another category of drawables/values folders.

Answer (score 2):

You can create same layout for all screen sizes, small, normal, large and x large.
How can you do that: Make new XML layout file in layout folder, make it so it has same name as the layout you want to modify to fit for all screen sizes. Click next, and there will be some options shown, find Size and insert it. Then you will be able to chose which screen size you want.
And when launched, system will chose best screen size for device.
Repeat for all 4 screen sizes. Hope this helps

Comment: As I said just creating 4 folders wasn't enough to deal with all the potential sizes.